# How to install App with custom fonts on a device?

Tags: android, fonts, installation

I have a problem with installing an App on a device. It is a Samsung Galaxy Mini running Android 2.2.1 sdk version 8. The app is running fine in the emulator. Now I wanted to test it on a real device, however, I cannot get it installed. The installation starts, but ends with a message APPLICATION NOT INSTALLED. I checked the logs and there seems to be some problem with custom fonts. The log says:

10-13 19:07:30.513 E/PackageParser(  177): Package xxxxx has no certificates at entry assets/fonts/LiberationMono-Bold.ttf; ignoring!

Why does Android want a certificate from me for that fonts? And why does it not want the certificate in the emulator? Please help.

Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is probably not properly signed, or (less likely), this is a bug in Galaxy Mini. Each APK (jar) entry has to be signed. Clean, re-export and try again. You can check the signatures/certificate with the `jarsigner -verbose -verify -certs your.apk`.

Comment: Does it have to be signed? I mean, I don't want to sell in the Android Market. It is just a custom app. I exported it through the option in Eclipse - Export Unsigned APK.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Every Android .apk needs to be signed if it is going to be installed on a phone, even if you're not installing through the Market.

Your fonts have not been signed properly, I think you can manually try this

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Users\Wesley\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android D:\test.apk androiddebugkey
```